# Jekyll fonts not changing with css

Tags: html, css, fonts, jekyll

I just set up a basic jekyll site on github pages (check www.umbertomichelucci.com). Now I am testing the blogging and I would like to change the font of the blog title (found here http://www.umbertomichelucci.com/blog/) to match all other fonts. I changed the css (http://www.umbertomichelucci.com/css/main.css) file (I am not an expert, so bear with me) but nothing seems to work. Anyone could help me out?

Thanks in advance, Umberto

Comment: Seems that it's the same font. Maybe you have cache on the old main.css file? Or do you mean the fact that the title is bold?

Comment: Yep... I cleared the cache and didn't realize it was the same font. Sorry. Thanks for checking... Kind of embarassing... Must be too tired.

Comment: That's ok, we all have been there.
Just a tip: Update your <link src=""> code and add a query string to force a recache. for instance: <link src="main.css?v=1.0.2">.

Comment: Thanks. Will update that.